# VCL: limit too many GET requests on same url

Tags: cdn, varnish

We are experiencing a problem where twice a day (when we send out a newsletter using a third service provider) the home page gets hit by thousands of requests from a particular bot for about 3-5 minutes. Such traffic seems to be generated by a legit bot and it creates fake data on our third parties analytics aggregators. We wonder if we could block/deny such traffic without penalizing the bot and its IP’s. We would like to be able to set in the VCL a sort of rule to block/deny/reject traffic when GET requests from the same user-agent hit the same exact URL too many times in a very short period of time. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is the URL in question embedded in your emails? Maybe some email gateways are prefetching it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using the vsthrottle VMOD: https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules/blob/master/src/vmod_vsthrottle.vcc.

Comment: The URL is not working

Comment: The new equivalent one is easy to find: https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules/blob/master/src/vmod_vsthrottle.vcc :)